# Component doesn't re-render when Redux state is changed - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have `RowsCont` with `renderRows`

```
renderRows = () => {

    let result = [];

    const {rows} = this.props;
    console.log('RENDER');
    console.log(rows);
    for(let key in rows){
        result.push(<Row={rows[key].id} 
            onHover={this.onHover}
            row={rows[key]}/>);
        }
    return result;
};
....
render(){<div>{this.renderRows()}</div>}

....
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log('mapState');
    console.log(state.rows.rows);
    return  {
        rows: state.rows.rows,
    }
}
```

Row Component:

```
    render(){

        return (
            <div>
                <div>{this.props.row.id}</div>
                <div>{this.props.row.value}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Rows is a collection of objects, each like this: `{id: 5, value: 'some value'}`

I have reducer, which changes the value of an object with specific id:

```
case 'SET_NEW_ROW_VALUE':
        let currentRows = state.rows;
        const changedIndex = currentRows .findIndex((obj) => obj.id === action.id);

        currentRows [changedIndex].value = action.value;

        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            rows: currentRows 
});
```

Everything works, but, if state is changed, the component doesn't re-render.
I am sure that state is changed, because I see the new state in `mapStateToProps` with `console.log`, every time when it is changed, but I don't see `console.log` from `renderRows`.

Each row component has and  `onHover`. If I hover the row, it is re-rendered and I see the new state for the row with the new value.

Comment: In this line `result.push(<Rowkey={row[key].id} `, I notices that it should be `rows` instead of `row` should it be `result.push(<Rowkey={rows[key].id} `

Comment: Yes, it is `rows`. * Edited.

Answer (score 3):

Your component is not rerendering because **your object is the same as it was before**

In a rendering cycle, React does a diff check on the new incoming props. If anything is different, it re-renders. In your case, the object is the same object as before.

As an example:

```
var rows = {id: 1, value: 'someVal'};
var oldRows = rows;
rows.id = 2;
rows.value = 'someNewVal';

console.log(rows === oldRows); // => true
```

React does a diff check between the `rows` and the `oldRows` and sees that the object itself is the same! Since the diff check sees equality, no re-rendering occurs.

The easiest way around this is to **update prop values by their primitives** within the object.

For example this will force a rerendering cycle when a change occurs:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log('mapState');
    console.log(state.rows.rows);
    return  {
        id: state.rows.rows.id,
        value: state.rows.rows.value
    }
}
```

If an object is absolutely necessary to be passed to your component, you can create a new object in your redux stores. Something like `state.rows = Object.assign({}, oldRows)` should do the trick.

Comment: but `state.rows.rows.value` is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

in redux you should **never mutate the state**, so `currentRows[changedIndex].value = action.value;` is forbidden

Here is a possible solution :

```
case 'SET_NEW_ROW_VALUE':
    const rows = state.rows.map(
      (row, index) => row.id !== action.id ? 
          row : 
          {...row, value: action.value}
    );

    return {...state, rows};
```

In your solution, you don't have a new reference for the prop `state.rows` after executing the case `SET_NEW_ROW_VALUE`. As `react-redux` use `shallow comparison` (`===` operator) to detect if an object has changed, with your solution the component will not be re-rendered as `state.rows` will be the same object (same reference) than before

Comment: But `currentRows` isn't the state , it is another variable (currentRows), because `let currentRows = state.rows;` or I am missing something ?

Comment: actually `currentRows` is one part of your state (=> `state.rows`), so if you mutate `currentRows` you also mutate the `state`

Comment: oh, pass by reference :). Thanks !